# Windows 7 how to enable/disable services to troubleshoot black screen on login?

Tags: windows-7, services, safe-mode, black-screen-of-death

This morning after starting my Windows 7 PC I found myself logging into a completely black screen (no mouse cursor as some people get with this similar problem). The Windows 7 login screen comes up, the associated chime/sound plays and I can enter my password. I see the "Welcome" message and blue spinning neon ball, then my monitor goes completely black, no cursor.

ctrl-shift-esc and ctrl-alt-del don't do anything at that point. I see a common solution is to bring up the task manager, kill the explorer process then run a new one as a common fix, but I can't do that.

I can log into any of the 3 safe modes (I'm logged into the safe mode with networking right now).

I've been trying to get the black screen login resolved for 10 hours now and I'm not having any luck. I'd like to try booting up with various services on/off to see if I can track it down to a service.

When I do a msconfig logged in via safe mode I see all the services are checked but the vast majority of them have a status of stopped.

If I unchecked every stopped service and restarted, would that essentially boot me up in the same manner as the safe mode I'm in (even though I don't boot up in safe mode)? Could I then just start checking some services and reboot to see if I can narrow it down to a particular service causing the problem?

I'm not incredibly technical when it comes to Windows and troubleshooting this problem has not been the easiest for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since Safe mode is working, rather than manually trying to fix or stop Stop services one at a time, you can [let Windows try to repair itself](https://www.howtogeek.com/222532/how-to-repair-corrupted-windows-system-files-with-the-sfc-and-dism-commands/). There are two command-line tools, SFC and DISM, which do the work without supervision.

- Open a CMD window with Administrative privilege: Click the Start button; in the *Search* box, type cmd, and then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER simultaneously.
- In the CMD window, enter **sfc /scannow** and wait for this to finish (~1/2 hour, perhaps).
- After SFC completes, you can follow up by entering **DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth** to fix more issues. Again, this takes some time.

If all goes well, try a normal reboot. I not, repeat the above procedures, but get help examining error messages.

Hope this fixes the issue.

Comment: I ran sfc /SCANNOW and some other command like a disk fix with /f /r at the end earlier today. I lost those browser tabs when I did a system restore so don't recall the second command, but it definitely wasn't the second one you mention above. It ran for a while and just rebooted back to the black screen on login.  I'll give your suggestion a go tomorrow am, I'm heading to bed soon.